# Android image saved using getExternalStoragePublicDirectory wont show up in internal storage

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, internal-storage

Im working on an some app where I need to take 3 images before I submit them and the related data.
I have the following code :

Listeners :

```
View.OnClickListener imgListeners = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String sSuffix = "_PIC";
            String sElementName = poleId.getText().toString();
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.ImagePoleId:
                    sSuffix = "_ID";
                    break;
                case R.id.ImagePole:
                    sSuffix = "_POLE";
                    break;
                case R.id.ImagePoleBulbs:
                    sSuffix = "_BULBS";
                    break;
            }

            takeCameraPic(sElementName, sSuffix + ".jpg");
        }
    };
```

Setting the listeners :

```
    idImgButton.setOnClickListener(imgListeners);
    poleImgButton.setOnClickListener(imgListeners);
    bulbsImgButton.setOnClickListener(imgListeners);
```

And the function used in the listeners :

```
private void takeCameraPic(String elementName ,String picNameSuffix) {
    if (elementName.equals("")) return;
    idImgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), elementName + picNameSuffix);
    Uri idImgUri = Uri.fromFile(idImgFile);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, idImgUri);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

When I enter the app, everything works fine, the camera pops up, I can take the image and go back.
But when I look for the image in the entire internal storage, its just not there. I've checked the DCIM \ PICTURES folders and nothing.
The only picture that was saved using the app says in the pic information that it was saved on the following folder :

> /storage/emulated/0/Pictures

Comment: Check `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234897/images-not-being-saved-when-picture-is-taken-by-camera-app-that-isnt-the-stock`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM` instead of `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` this gets you to

> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM

folder. You can then create Pictires folder and save image there.